# element attribute is set by both jquery and php , but only php works

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to set an element attribute, to set the slider range. I used ajax to get the data from a php file and send it to attribute. It already gets the value and looks great, but it DOESN'T WODK.

Then i used php to get the data and put it there , now it looks the same as before but now it WORKS.

the problem is , i need this variable to update all the time and the only way for me is jquery and ajax. So , how can i do it as ajax?

***here is the code:***

PHP VERSION:

```
<input type="text" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="<?php swordsman($con,$username); ?>" id="swordsman_slider">
```

THE OUTPUT:

```
<input type="text" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="0,8" id="swordsman_slider" style="display: none;">
```

---

AJAX VERSION:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'slider_max.php',
    type:'POST',
    data:{swordsman:up},
    success:function(data){
        $('#swordsman_slider').attr("data-slider-range",data);
    }
});
```

THE OUTPUT:

```
<input type="text" data-slider="true" id="swordsman_slider" data-slider-range="0,8" style="display: none;">
```

---

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: what is data value?can you do console.log(data) and see what it does or share the php code where the ajax gets that value :)

Comment: At a guess, the plugin takes the value and uses it for setup *before* you've assigned it. I'm sure their documentation tells you how to update it after it's initialized.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder : yes , exactly , thats the problem , it gets the value before it's assigned.

Comment: @guradio : the php code is for test , it's just " echo '0,8' ; "

Answer (score 0):

can you use prop() method for setting data range,
replace following code in your ajax success callback.

$( "input" ).prop( "data-slider-range", data );

Comment: FYI: I found out that you can't use `.data('slider-range', data)` since the `data-` attribute has a hyphen in it and `jQuery.data` does not like hyphens.  This was a problem I had in the past, so I make it a habit to not use hyphens anymore when assigning data attributes, only 1 hyphen and it goes after `data`.

Comment: @Purushotham :  TNX , I test that right now , but it didn't work.